# YA fantasy book; a boy and a girl meet in a dream world

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I have been searching for this for years! I got it out of the library when I was 12 or 13 so about 15 years ago now, but I have no clue when it would have been released and my family have no idea what I'm talking about.

All I can remember is that it had quite a plain white/grey cover and the title was something to do with dreams or dreaming?

What I can remember of it was that there were two main characters, I think it was told from two points of view, a boy and a girl and they met in a dream world. There was a journey involved - either a quest type of thing or a race maybe? They were preparing for a battle or fight at the end of the book, so it's possibly a series or duology.

Comment: It might help if you gave us more details (perhaps you just need a prompt to remember) there's a [checklist for story ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2041/checklist-for-story-identification) which might help.

Comment: I'm not confident this is the answer, but could it be _Marianne Dreams_ by Catherine Storr? It was made into a film called Paperhouse, which I remember well, but I don't remember much about the book.

Comment: Possibly The Rainbow Opera by Elizabeth Knox? Apparently it was called Dreamhunter outside the UK, and has some greyish covers under that name.

Comment: Could it be Strange the Dreamer by Laini Taylor? It's part of a three book series and involves a boy and girl who meet in dreams. I believe it was published in 2017 though so it's not old enough...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wanted to update this, I was browsing through similar questions on goodreads and found the answer to this!

The book was Waking Dream by Rhiannon Lassiter, and I have now ordered myself a copy. It looks like the only detail I remembered accurately was that there was a shared dream involved..

Thanks to everyone else who answered, most of the books mentioned have found their way onto my to read list.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly **[The Beginning Place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beginning_Place)** (1980) by Ursula Le Guin.

No "dream" in the title, so I may be wrong. But it has a boy and a girl from our world, Hugh Rogers and Irene Pannis, who individually come across a gateway to Tembreabrezi, an idyllic, unchanging world of eternal twilight (time flows much more slowly than in the outside world, making it always evening). The chapters are told alternately from the viewpoints of the two young people. The town they visit in Tembreabrezi is closed off because of a monster that causes fear, and the two embark together on a mission to save the town and reopen the roads, eventually killing the monster. The book doesn't end before the battle as you recall (and there is no sequel); nor can I find any 'plain white/grey cover', at least for an English edition. But the other details fit very well.

[image: Cover of "The Beginning Place" by Ursula K. Le Guin. The cover shows an off-white background, with a stretched clock in the foreground and a forest midground.]

[image: Cover of "The Beginning Place" by Ursula K. Le Guin. The cover shows a blond-haired boy holding a sword standing in the midst of several trees.]

Answer (score 1):

Just possibly [*Seaward*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11308.Seaward) (1983), by Susan Cooper?

> His name is West. Her name is Cally. They speak different languages and come from different countries thousands of miles apart, but they do not know that. What they do know are the tragedies that took their parents, then wrenched the two of them out of reality, into a strange and perilous world through which they must travel together, knowing only that they must reach the sea. Together West and Cally embark upon a strange and sometimes terrifying quest, learning to survive and to love and, at last, the real secret of their journey.

Comment: Can you explain why this would match? Right now, it's just a title.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, please take the [tour] and visit the [help], although a member of the site has added details to the answer, we would still appreciate you [edit]ing in an explanation as to why you think this matches.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [Marianne Dreams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marianne_Dreams)

Filmed as [Paperhouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paperhouse_(film)).   I've seen the film, but I haven't read the book.

A girl draws a picture of a house. When she sleeps she enters the house in her dreams. She meets a boy there.  The boy is a real person in the waking world. They battle an Ogre, who is a version of the girl's alcoholic father.